# Spark Java: Passing variable number of arguments to a function

Tags: java, apache-spark

Please see section "[Programmatically Specifying the Schema](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema)". Java section.

The example works. But I have a question about this particular code snippet.

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = people.map(
new Function<String, Row>() {
public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
String[] fields = record.split(",");
  return Row.create(fields[0], fields[1].trim());
}
```

The Row create method is being called with a static number of objects determined at compile time.

However, in my code, I need to call the `Row.create` method for a dynamic number of arguments.

I will only know the number of fields at run time

For example, it may be one of:

`return Row.create(fields[0], fields[1].trim(), fields[2]);`

or

```
return Row.create(fields[0]);
```

or

```
return Row.create(fields[0],fields[1].trim(), fields[2], fields[3],fields[4]);
```

How do I do it?

Comment: Some people have suggested that "three dots after the argument" will solve my problem. It wont. The method i am calling already accepts a dynamic number of arguments. The problem is in calling. I wont know how many arguments to pass to it at compile time. I will know it at runtime. The problem is not the function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it. Worked for me.

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = people.map(
  new Function<String, Row>() {
   public Row call(String record) throws Exception {
     String[] fields = record.split(",");         
    //return Row.create(fields[0], fields[1].trim());
      Object[] fields_converted = fields;
      return Row.create(fields_converted);
      }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using elipsis in your implemented method as below.

```
public static void create(String ...arg) { ... }
```

Elipsis accept `n` number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a method to take multiple arguments by using three dots after the argument, for example:

```
public static <return_type> create(String...args){
    // Yoo can now use the String[] args
}
```

Replace  with your desired return type.
Please change the signature of your **call** method as you have not specified a return type for it!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in the same situation

```
new Function<String, Row>(String s) {
    public Row call(String s){
        int n = /* width of actual schema */
        Object rec[] = new Object[n];
        for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            rec[i] = /* Something that aligns with the type of #i field */
        return Row.create( rec );
    }
}
```

There might be dragons here. My version compiles, looks good, not tested yet.